# What is the meaning of 'role','title','alt' in DOJO Mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, voiceover, dojox.mobile

I am a dojo fresher, Here is a mobile application which developed by Dojo Mobile.

and I found it can't work when I open the ios VoiceOver.

the **data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView"** component can't scroll any more.

I checked the dojo website and found the solution(https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/faq.html):

> **How do I develop applications which support iOS VoiceOver?**
>
> to set the **alt**, **title** and **role** attributes. VoiceOver will read widgets
>   with these attributes set. See **tests/test_a11y.html** for examples.
>   However, the value of a SpinWheel can not be read by VoiceOver in 1.8.Make sure

follow the guide I visited the page **tests/test_a11y.html**(https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/mobile/tests/test_a11y.html) and I do find the code include the **alt,title,role** attributes:

Here is the question: what's the meaning of these three attributes,can I add the attributes to every Dojo components in my code?and how to decide the value of these attributes?

and I found from the **tests/test_a11y.html** that some dojo components include just role attribute but some others include all the three.it makes me very confusing...:

here is My code ,how to reform it：

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ContentPane" id="ReceiptsAttach" class="receipts">    
    <div id="receiptsAttachContent" data-dojo-attach-point="dataContent"  data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" class="selectContent"></div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For title:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

> Contains a text representing advisory information related to the element it belongs to. Such information can typically, but not necessarily, be presented to the user as a tooltip.

for Alt:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

> Alternative text in case an image can't be displayed.

For role, it is about Aria role.
You can see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

> The role attribute defines what the general type of object is (such as an article, alert, or slider)

A list of roles can be found here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#abstract_roles

Comment: I got the point. the 'role' 'title' 'alt' are not the special attributes in dojo